# Youtube Data API no carga imgenes Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Tengo un problema, en visual studio xamarin sobre el data API youtube y el problema es lo siguiente: 
Tengo la url de mi canal que es este (UCY5x6J_25SwOql1D26AbSSQ) y mi id de la lista de youtube (PLKvHBMzwK-kKaDq00EQnPC-vk2y4q3ygH) pero al momento de cargar la aplicación no sale nada. pero cargo otro canal que no es el mio y me funciona igual manera con la lista de youtube no se a que se deba este problema, he estado buscando configuraciones en youtube pero no he encontrado nada.
ayuda por favor

[image: url]

```
        private const string ApiKey = "";

        // doc : https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list 
        private string apiUrlForChannel = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&maxResults=20&channelId="
            + "UCY5x6J_25SwOql1D26AbSSQ" // este es mi canal
            //+ "Your_ChannelId"
            + "&key="
            + ApiKey;

        // doc : https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list
        private string apiUrlForPlaylist = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&maxResults=20&playlistId="
            + "PLKvHBMzwK-kKaDq00EQnPC-vk2y4q3ygH" //play lista id
            //+ "Your_PlaylistId"
            + "&key="
            + ApiKey;

        // doc : https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list
        private string apiUrlForVideosDetails = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,statistics&id="
            + "{0}"
          //  + "Sg5zNGpTE4w&t=4s"
            //+ "Your_Videos_Id"
            + "&key="
            + ApiKey;

        private List<YoutubeItem> _youtubeItems;

        public List<YoutubeItem> YoutubeItems
        {
            get { return _youtubeItems; }
            set
            {
                _youtubeItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public YoutubeViewModel()
        {
            InitDataAsync();
        }

        public async Task InitDataAsync()
        {

            var videoIds = await GetVideoIdsFromChannelAsync();

           // var videoIds = await GetVideoIdsFromPlaylistAsync();
        }

        private async Task<List<string>> GetVideoIdsFromChannelAsync()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(apiUrlForChannel);

            var videoIds = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                JObject response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

                var items = response.Value<JArray>("items");

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    videoIds.Add(item.Value<JObject>("id")?.Value<string>("videoId"));
                }

                YoutubeItems = await GetVideosDetailsAsync(videoIds);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
            }

            return videoIds;
        }

        private async Task<List<string>> GetVideoIdsFromPlaylistAsync()
        {

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(apiUrlForPlaylist);

            var videoIds = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                JObject response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

                var items = response.Value<JArray>("items");

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    videoIds.Add(item.Value<JObject>("contentDetails")?.Value<string>("videoId"));
                };

                YoutubeItems = await GetVideosDetailsAsync(videoIds);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
            }

            return videoIds;
        }

        private async Task<List<YoutubeItem>> GetVideosDetailsAsync(List<string> videoIds)
        {

            var videoIdsString = "";
            foreach (var s in videoIds)
            {
                videoIdsString += s + ",";
            }

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(string.Format(apiUrlForVideosDetails, videoIdsString));

            var youtubeItems = new List<YoutubeItem>();

            try
            {
                JObject response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

                var items = response.Value<JArray>("items");

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    var snippet = item.Value<JObject>("snippet");
                    var statistics = item.Value<JObject>("statistics");

                    var youtubeItem = new YoutubeItem
                    {
                        Title = snippet.Value<string>("title"),
                        Description = snippet.Value<string>("description"),
                        ChannelTitle = snippet.Value<string>("channelTitle"),
                        PublishedAt = snippet.Value<DateTime>("publishedAt"),
                        VideoId = item?.Value<string>("id"),
                        DefaultThumbnailUrl = snippet?.Value<JObject>("thumbnails")?.Value<JObject>("default")?.Value<string>("url"),
                        MediumThumbnailUrl = snippet?.Value<JObject>("thumbnails")?.Value<JObject>("medium")?.Value<string>("url"),
                        HighThumbnailUrl = snippet?.Value<JObject>("thumbnails")?.Value<JObject>("high")?.Value<string>("url"),
                        StandardThumbnailUrl = snippet?.Value<JObject>("thumbnails")?.Value<JObject>("standard")?.Value<string>("url"),
                        MaxResThumbnailUrl = snippet?.Value<JObject>("thumbnails")?.Value<JObject>("maxres")?.Value<string>("url"),

                        ViewCount = statistics?.Value<int>("viewCount"),
                        LikeCount = statistics?.Value<int>("likeCount"),
                        DislikeCount = statistics?.Value<int>("dislikeCount"),
                        FavoriteCount = statistics?.Value<int>("favoriteCount"),
                        CommentCount = statistics?.Value<int>("commentCount"),

                        Tags = (from tag in snippet?.Value<JArray>("tags") select tag.ToString())?.ToList(),
                    };

                    youtubeItems.Add(youtubeItem);
                }

                return youtubeItems;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return youtubeItems;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Tu canal *o los otros que hayas probado* tiene alguna configuración de privacidad?, ¿tienes manera de validar los Id's de los canales usando la console de google developers?, ¿tienes algún error `400, 405, etc`? - escribe la excepción "si la hay": `catch (Exception exception) { string err = exception.ToString(); }` y [edit] tu pregunta con los detalles de la excepción.

Comment: Hola jasilva ya quedo solucionado el pequeño problema era sobre el tema de privacidad en la parte de verificación. por eso no se mostraba las imágenes, muchas gracias por tu ayuda...